# Why can't I set custom UIButton to the size I want?

Tags: swift, uibutton, size, frame, custom-button

I set up a button but the button can't become the size I want, I don't understand why, please help me thanks

attach my code here

```
var confirmButton : UIButton = {
    let confirmButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    confirmButton.backgroundColor = .red
    confirmButton.setTitle("確認", for: .normal)
    confirmButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    confirmButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 2000, height: 30)

    return confirmButton
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    confirmButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(confirmButton)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        //confirmButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 12),
        //confirmButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 100),
    ])
}
```

[view hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbd9x.png)

Comment: Could you please attach the image of the desired result and the current one?

Comment: Right now your doesn’t use neither autoresizing mask nor constraints based layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is probably happening because you're setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  as false but not giving any additional constraints.
Also, it is cancelling the frame configuration because you've set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints.

Try removing translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints, by default it is true, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, it finally worked! I guess I haven't figured out when to use translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints vs NSLayoutConstraint. I don't understand what the naysayers are trying to convey. I think this is a common problem for novices after referring to other people's code

Comment: When you want to implement AutoLayout, you have to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints as false and then use NSLayoutConstraint to set manually the constraints. Take a look at this [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/140/the-auto-layout-cheat-sheet), maybe it can help you